# Why would memory access on x86 be slower when aligned to first 4 bytes of the cache line?

Tags: java, performance, memory, x86

In writing a blog post on [unaligned/aligned direct memory access](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/direct-memory-alignment-in-java.html) I've hit a result I struggle to explain: If my memory access is aligned to the first 4 bytes I see a measurable difference in performance for the worse when data structure fits into L1 cache. In some cases other locations are 20% faster.

The article goes into allot more detail about the experiment and method, but here is the summary:

1. Allocate a block of memory which fits into L1(32k on my laptop, use hwloc/check the spec of your cpu to find out). Align block to cacheline size(usually 64b, check your hardware). The allocation is done upfront and not measured.
2. Iterate over the memory block and write a long(some value) into each cacheline in a given offset(effectively causing an unaligned write if the offset is not a multiple of 8).
3. Iterate over memory block and read from same offset and verify the value is as expected.

Why should there be any difference in performance when offset is 0-3?

The essence of the measured code(as per request in comment):

```
for (address = startingAddress; address < limit; address += CACHE_LINE_SIZE) {
    Unsafe.putLong(address, value);
}
for (address = startingAddress; address < limit; address += CACHE_LINE_SIZE) {
   if (Unsafe.getLong(address) != value)
       throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Where starting address is cache aligned + offset.
Full experiment is available [here](https://github.com/nitsanw/psy-lob-saw/blob/master/experiments/alignment/UnalignedMemoryAccessCostBenchmark.java):

Comment: Far too little meat to tell. Show some actual code. Most likely you do not read from where you think you're reading OR your code structure triggers the CPU to perform a speculative read. BTW the pagesize paragraph contained not what I would expect. The term pagesize I know from the context of memory management (PMMU), not IO, which would also make more sense considering the topic.

Comment: The code is in the post and also on GitHub, I can cut and paste it here if it helps, but was hoping to avoid repeating it in one extra place.

Comment: @Durandal How would the code trigger a speculative read from 0-3 byte offset, but not from anywhere else? The term pagesize is not in the question and is indeed not that relevant to it.

Comment: Have you tried this in something closer to the hardware? Such as C or C++?

Comment: @Mysticial Not yet... but have examined the generated assembly and found nothing to explain it. It is just a MOV...

Comment: You have too many uncontrolled variables.  There can also be significant variations from one generation of core to the next in cache behavior.  I recommend:  (1) Write your critical code in assembly so you can account for every instruction (2) Enable user mode performance counters by setting the PCE bit in CR4  (3) Identify the relevant icache, dcache and prefetching counters and read them with the rdpmc instruction in tight proximity to your critical code.  By inspecting the performance counters, you'll get a clue what's happening in the micro architecture.

Comment: @srking fair enough, although I must admit I'm not very familiar with the tools involved. I was hoping someone might have an idea given the invariance of the code apart from the access offset. If no answer materializes I shall go down the route you describe.

Comment: @Nitsan it's a tough but interesting goal to understand where every cycle went.  Even with the exact same machine and exact same CPU, one box could have prefetching enabled (via a BIOS setting) and the other not.  You'll be forever scratching your head without a direct look into the micro-architectural behavior.

Comment: @srking I ran the same test on 2 machines and got the same result, have 2 more I can try it on for good measure... The counters I measured using perf showed me nothing unusual... still scratching ;)

Comment: @Nitsan - One place to start:  For L1 data cache miss count, subtract the rdpmc result at the start of the test from the rdpmc result at the end of the test.  Do you see the number of L1 misses you expected your test to cause?